# Replace dropdown with bootstrap-select with keyword search

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, bootstrap-select

**TL;DR;** I would like to replace the standard bootstrap dropdown in my Django form with [bootstrap-select with keywords](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#key-words). Is there a way to make `{% render_field %}` add `data-tokens=` to each option?

---

I have a page where a user can tag a person in the photo. The corresponding form looks like this:

```
class AddFaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Face
        fields = ('person', ...)
```

and the template form like this:

```
<form id="face-add-form" action="{% url 'photos:faces' photo.name %}" method="post" class="form-inline" hidden>
{% csrf_token %}
{% render_field form.person class+="form-control dropdown" title="Person"%}
...
```

This renders the person selector as a standard dropdown, with options listed as

```
<option value="139">XXX</option>
<option value="121">YYY</option>
...
```

I can replace it with the bootstrap-select by replacing `class+="form-control dropdown"` with `class+="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"`. However the options will still be listed as with the standard dropdown. To enhance the search, I need to add `data-tokens` to each option, e.g.:

```
<option value="139" data-tokens="nickname-XXX">XXX</option>
<option value="121" data-tokens="nickname-YYY">YYY</option>
```

Is there a way to do it without manually rendering the form?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a beautiful solution yet, but of course there is a workaround without `{% render_field %}`:

```
<select name="person" title="Person" id="id_person" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
    <option value="None"></option>
    {% for p in people %}
        <option value="{{ p.id }}" data-tokens="{{ p.all_names }}">{{ p.full_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```